# XML Slurper - empty string for attributes

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

When parsing an attribute, the slurper sets an empty string when an attribute is not found.

For e.g., `car.setOwner(node.@owner.text());`

In the above code, if the owner attribute is not found, then the slurper sets a blank string ("").

In my case, I'd rather leave it as null than setting an empty string.

Is it possible to configure the Slurper not to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we distinguish between *configure* and using the *Meta Object Protocol* (MOP), then we can state that it is **not** possible to configure XmlSlurper as you describe, but it **is** possible to use the MOP.

For configure, note the following:

```
def node = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<car>No Owner</car>' )

def attr = node.@owner
assert groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes == attr.getClass()
```

If you [look at the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-xml/2.2.2/groovy/util/slurpersupport/Attributes.java) for `Attributes.text()` (in this case, Groovy 2.2.2), it is clear that this cannot be configured to return null.

For MOP, we can capture the original `Attributes.text()` method and then override it:

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.*

def originalText = Attributes.metaClass.getMetaMethod("text")

Attributes.metaClass.text = { ->
    def result = originalText.invoke(delegate)
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        result = null
    }
    result
}

// no owner
def node = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<car>No Owner</car>')
def attr = node.@owner
assert null == attr.text()

// with owner
node = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<car owner="codetojoy"></car>')
attr = node.@owner
assert "codetojoy" == attr.text()
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I'd like this functionality throughout the project (i.e. across many groovy classes). Do I need to place the above code in a base class that all other groovy classes extend? Or, is there any other option?

Comment: Here is the doc on the ExpandoMetaClass - http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass . Your comment question is too broad to answer here. (e.g. is this a webapp? simple script? etc). Be warned that MOP stuff is amazingly powerful, and with it that old chestnut about concomitant responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We've a grails application, so I'm a bit confused where this code should be placed.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
car.setOwner(node.@owner.text() ?: null)
```

Comment: That's cheeky. Thanks for letting me know "The King" operator :).